# I receive more than one final transcript of the Speech to text IBM cloud service

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I am working with the Speech to text service on a project in Angular, I am converting the voice coming in from the microphone to text and when I receive transcriptions sometimes the service returns more than one final transcription.
There is some way to control this, as I need only one final transcript returned.

These are the parameters I send to the service

```js
 accessToken: a.token,
      format: true,
      extractResults: true,
      objectMode: true,
      model: "es-PE_NarrowbandModel"
```

```js
  var rsOpts = assign(
    {
      contentType: 'audio/l16;rate=16000',
      interimResults: true,
      keywords: ["ok", "okay"],
      keywordsThreshold: 0.5,
      wordConfidence: true,
      backgroundAudioSuppressio: 0.5,
      inactivity_timeout: -1
    },
    options
  );
```

In the documentation it mentions that interimResults is where the number of transcripts is limited but by putting it in false I don't receive any transcripts

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `interimResults` then that should be set to `false`. That will not give you any results if its not a `final`. If you want to see only 1 final result then you need to set `maxAlternatives` to `1`.

If you are only getting results when you switch on `interimResults` then this indicates that you are never getting the final transcription. ie. the audio input is never terminating. What you might need to do is modify `inactivityTimeout` to a value large enough so that between sentence pauses are ignored, but smaller than the default of 30 seconds, so that the end of a track can be detected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

As I understood the service documentation, interimResults = false is used for offline or batch transcription. But I am sending the voice from the microphone directly to the service for transcription.

Now by default I get only one final transcription = true, but there are times when the final transcription = true is returned between 2 to 3 times.